# Array to string convertion Error Cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to display an icon image and give that image a link with the intern details but not working. I am trying to do like within a cakephp code i am trying to show an image and when a user will click on that image it will show another page with these `array('action' => 'detail'), $intern['Intern']['id'])` details.Here is my code below. What's wrong with these code

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link(($this->Html>image('.img/resource/hover_down_icon.png')),array('action' => 'detail'), $intern['Intern']['id']),array('css' =>'image_down_icon');
?>
```

Comment: Please use the formatting to make your question readable.

Comment: Make your question more clear,so as to understand.Make it fast,or it will get downvote

Comment: I am in the learning stage so i will surely give focus on my asking questions next time.thank you for your support.

Comment: Don't worry,,We are all here to support you.

Comment: Not just the next question please format this one. Format your code to be reabable, and specify the error.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to display an image and give it a link,Use this type of method

```
echo  '<a href="Link you want"><img src="hover_down_icon.png"  /></a>';
```

OR

```
echo  "<a href=\"Link you want.html\"><img src=\"hover_down_icon.png\"  /> </a>";
```

if you want to send details to another page set the details in a variable and send ,then retrive value at next page by

```
//Using GET, POST or COOKIE.
$var_value = $_REQUEST['details'];
```

Try to alter your code with adequate changes

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i think i cant able to make my question readable. I am trying to do like within a cakephp code i am trying to show an image and when a user will click on that image it will show another page with these array('action' => 'detail'), $intern['Intern']['id']) details.

Comment: I think the code I shown above will help you..at <a href=-->>You should write code for which page you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong perameter in the action array .you need to use `array('action' => 'detail', $intern['Intern']['id'])` as one parameter. Try this one

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link(($this->Html>image('.img/resource/hover_down_icon.png')),array('action' => 'detail', $intern['Intern']['id']),array('css' =>'image_down_icon'));
?>
```